# Tratamento de Erros Paramiko (Python)

Tags: python

Olá,

Estou montando um script onde o usuario irá se autenticar em um equipamento, se tudo der certo o código continua senão ele mostra uma mensagem de erro. Estou usando a biblioteca Paramiko para fazer a sessão com o equipamento, a conexão está ok e ele retorna a mensagem que eu desejo quando a conexão falha, porém aparece outro erro logo em seguida.

MEU CÓDIGO:

```
username = raw_input("Username:")
password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")

remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

try:
    remote_conn_pre.connect('1.111.111.111', username=username, password=password)
except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
    print ("Erro de login.")
```

ERRO EM SEGUIDA:

```
  File "run.py", line 67, in <module>
    remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=username, password=password)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 380, in connect
    look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 603, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

Acredito que não estou sabendo usar o **paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException** direito, alguém pode me ajudar?

E mais uma dúvida, tem como eu fazer caso ele dê erro, ele retornar para o usuário digitar o username/password novamente?

Desculpe, sou meio novo em programação e Python, por isso as dúvidas.
Muito obrigado!

Comment: já tentou só except sem o `paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException`?

Answer (score 1):

Você não esta tratando a exceção de forma correta. 
No bloco `try except` adicione a tratativa da exceção de autentificação

```
try:
    remote_conn_pre.connect('1.111.111.111', username=username, password=password)
except AuthenticationException:
    print ("Erro de login.")
```

ou

```
try:
    remote_conn_pre.connect('1.111.111.111', username=username, password=password)
except paramiko.AuthenticationException as err:
    print ("Erro de login: " + str(err)))
```

Leia a documentação da biblioteca, no casso do metodo `connect` do `client` ele da `raise` nas exceções de `BadHostKeyException` , `AuthenticationException`, `SSHException` e `socket.error`

http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.htm